# Recently opened items in Windows Explorer disappeared from the Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

My history of recently opened items in Windows Explorer disappeared from the Windows 7 Taskbar:

[image]

I've tried using used CCleaner to fix it, but it didn't help.

I did not install any updates, just installed the first time SP1 and that's all.

Strange that this also happened on another computer using Windows 7 at the same time.

Comment: Did you perform similar actions (install SP1, and/or run CCleaner) on the other computer that it happened on?

Comment: Please elaborate, as it's kind of hard to follow you description of what you've done.  You had a fresh system it was working on, then you installed SP1, and now they're cleared out and new ones are not added?  Is this right, and is this exactly the same thing done to the other computer?  Are these computers on a domain network?

Comment: Hello!
Thank you very much for your help, after what you told me, I could look better and found the solution here:  :::::::  http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-taskbar-explorer-icon-jump-list-not-working-in-windows-7

Comment: Excellent. You should use the information there and formulate an answer, and then enter it as an answer here. :)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is:
open Explorer and navigate to %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
folder.

Delete all the automaticDestinations-ms files you see here.
This will however clear the Jump List history for all your programs.

Restart the computer and open a few folders/files randomly to see if the Jump List is building up.

;)

Found at: thewindowsclub